# Creating a visual matrix on Excel that will show where a specific event date occurs within a date range. Is this possible?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a visual representation of when a specific event date occurs in a matrix of dates. However, I need that the event # (milestone) occur only once and not duplicate after the first instance. I included an image of what I have currently and my desired result. I want this to eventually become an event tracker for 50+ events (each row will be a separate event) so our team can see when our workload picks up and if I need to push back certain events so that we do not get too overwhelmed.

The first row includes the Event Numbers (colored light blue) and the standard timeline of dates to compare to (colored grey), extending about 3 years. The second row includes the dates associated with the event numbers in an array format (colored darker blue), plus the first function I tried:

```
=COUNTIF($A4:$M4, "<=" & $N$3:$AX$3)
```

This works accurately enough but is duplicating the values as shown. It counts the number of event dates that occur before each column date and returns the number of occurrences. It is also a SPILL function if that matters.

The second function I tried (third row) is:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(N$3, $A4:$M4, 1), "")
```

This function gives the same results as the COUNTIF function above, except it returns the column number in the event array when the event occurs for each cell. However, this still duplicates my values.

The fourth row are my desired results. As you can see, the first instance of each number occurs once and does not duplicate, and all other cells are left blank. Once I get a working function, I would like to recreate this for 50+ separate events and all their dates in the same columns as the first event.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Edit: Image not loading on post, link included by stack overflow. Hope it works this time...
[image]